# C++ Type issue - Slicing isse?

Tags: types, slice, c++98

TourManager.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>
#include <typeinfo>
#include "Tour.h"
#include "GuidedTour.h"

using namespace std;
class TourManager {

private:
    vector<Tour *> list;
    void setupTour();
    void callDisplayOnEach();

public:
    TourManager();
    void go();
};
```

TourManager.cpp

```
#include "TourManager.h"

TourManager::TourManager() {

    setupTour();
}

void TourManager::setupTour() {

    list.push_back(new Tour("BG002", "Botanical Gardens Entry Pass", 30.00));
    list.push_back(new GuidedTour("SK003", "Learn to Ski Adventure Tour", 240.00, "28/07/2008", "Zail S", 25));
}

void TourManager::callDisplayOnEach() {

    for(vector<Tour *>::iterator it = list.begin() ; it != list.end(); ++it) {

        (*(*it)).display();
    }
}
```

Guided tour is a sub class of the Tour. It overrides display method of the parent tour class.
However when I loop through tour objects vector and call display, it always call the tour::display even if the object is a GuidedTour.

What am I doing wrong here?

I'm using C++98
Many thanks.

Comment: Are your display methods are virtual?

Comment: what's a virtual method, sorry, I'm new to C++

Comment: a virtual method is a function or method whose behavior can be overridden within an inheriting class by a function with the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally figured it out.

In the tour class

```
virtual void display():
```

so it can be overridden in the subclass :D

Answer (score 1):

Both of your `display` methods must be virtual for this to work.

---

<s>Also, consider using an `std::unique_ptr`. Raw pointers should never **own** memory. It's also good for you because when the vector goes out of scope, the destructors of the unique pointers will clear the allocated memory for you.</s>

Nevermind, C++98 only has `std::auto_ptr`. The Boost libraries have their own smart pointers however. Look into [`boost::scoped_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.htm).

Comment: what's a virtual method, sorry, I'm new to C++

std::unique_ptr, can I use that with C++98?

Comment: Thank you, you saved my day!! virtual void display(): in the Tour class fixed it!!!

Comment: @Mohammad Ali Baydoun Actually, '(*(*it)).display()' works. (*(*it)) doesn't result in an object, but in a reference Tour& to the object. And a virtual function call through a reference is subject to dynamic dispatch, just as such a call through a pointer. Of course, '(*it)->display()' is a good practice.